# Как при ховере блока с прозрачностью оставить внутренние элементы видимыми?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

Как при ховере элемента и затемнении его с эффектом прозрачности сделать так, чтобы некоторые внутренние элементы (обе кнопки) были видны с исходной непрозрачностью?

```css
button {
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
.on-hover {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10%;
}
.frame {
  position: relative;
}
.frame:hover {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.frame:hover .on-hover {
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <p>текст</p>
  <img src="http://s00.yaplakal.com/pics/pics_original/9/3/8/462839.jpg" alt="веселый паровозик" width="200" height="200" />
  <button>кнопка</button>
  <button class="on-hover">выход</button>
</div>
```

Comment: можно - вы нести кнопки из контейнера, либо делать полупрозрачным не сам контейнер а его части

Comment: @soledar10 спасибо, но `opacity` должен срабатывать и на тексте, т.е. по всему блоку. я к тому, что какие-то элементы могут быть и после синей кнопки - тут упрощенный вариант

Comment: соледар? :-) я вообще два варианта предложил - один - вынести, второй плохо выразился, суть - сделать placeholder который будет полупрозрачным и показываться на ховере

Comment: @Grundy нет, нужно именно весь контейнер сделать полупрозрачным, не пытайтесь обойти тз

Comment: @Grundy про `placeholder` не очень понимаю - поясните

Comment: элемент который растянется над всем блоком

Comment: @Grundy каким образом он не будет перекрывать кнопки?

Comment: например с помощью установки z-index

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сделайте не `.frame:hover {opacity: 0.3}`, а `.frame:hover * {opacity: 0.3;}`

После чего для исключений установите `opacity: 1;`

https://jsfiddle.net/mh4vqk1c/

```css
button {
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
.on-hover {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10%;
}
.frame {
  position: relative;
}
.frame:hover * {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.frame:hover .on-hover {
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <p>текст</p>
  <img src="http://s00.yaplakal.com/pics/pics_original/9/3/8/462839.jpg" alt="веселый паровозик" width="200" height="200" />
  <button>кнопка</button>
  <button class="on-hover">выход</button>
</div>
```

Comment: в вопросе про обе кнопки было, но суть я думаю понятна :)

Comment: @Grundy, да, вторую потеряла :)

Answer (score 4):

еще такой вариант

```css
.frame {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.frame:hover:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
.frame:hover .on-hover {
  display: block;
  background-color: black;  
}

button {
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.on-hover {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30%;
}
.frame button{
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <p>текст</p>
  <img src="http://s00.yaplakal.com/pics/pics_original/9/3/8/462839.jpg" alt="веселый паровозик" width="200" height="200" />
  <button>кнопка</button>
  <button class="on-hover">выход</button>
</div>
```

Comment: как же долго я собирался дать ответ :-D кстати, в последнем правиле _.frame button.on-hover_ уже не нужен, они же обе _button_

Comment: Grundy поправил